# Event-Tracking for Google Analytics: different image-sources after page-reload for Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

On a page i have a class "banner". Within this class is an img-element with an external Link and an image.
After every Page reload the link and the img-src are changed . How can i track this different Images in Google Analytics.
Is there a way with Event-Tracking?

`<div class="banner"><a href="http://www.ticketcorner.ch/tickets.html?fun=erdetail&amp;affiliate=TCS&amp;doc=erdetaila&amp;erid=1754040" target="_blank"><img src="/media/uploads/banners/empire_web2.jpg"></a>
      </div>`

**Update:**

I edited the Code and hope this works in Analytics soon (It does not work at the moment):

Banner 1:

```
<div class="banner"><a href="http://www.plaza-zurich.ch/nu/events/event_list/" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Banner Click', 'Oh La La')"><img src="/media/uploads/banners/ohhlalacherie_plaza_nov16_960x112px.jpg"></a></div>
```

Banner 2 (after Page Reload):

```
 <div id="12" class="banner"><a href="http://www.ticketcorner.ch/tickets.html?fun=erdetail&amp;affiliate=TCS&amp;doc=erdetaila&amp;erid=1754040" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', ‘Banner Click', ‘Empire of');"><img src="/media/uploads/banners/empire_web2.jpg"></a></div>
```

Comment: What do you want to track, the event where the image changes? That would be harder to do as you would need to compare the current image with the previous image (ie. requiring "memory" via cookies, for example). If you know that the image changes each time, then what is the value of tracking that through an event?

Comment: The changing images are different ad-banners. My client would like to make an evaluation of the various ad-banners clicked in analytics. I thought the best way to track these different ad-banners in Analytics is with Event-Tracking.

Comment: You should just track each banner information as a hit scoped custom dimension. This way you know how often which banner was displayed to the user. Simply create a custom dimension with scope "hit", track the information on each page view. Within your reporting select the custom dimension and pageviews as your metric.

Comment: So you want to track when the banners are CLICKED, and not when the banner changes then, correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct.